# use three20 ui into interface builder

Tags: object, interface-builder, three20

I added to my project three20 lib, compile ok with no problem...
but If I wish add a TTLabel for example directly by Interface Builder, how can I do this?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three20 components are not supported yet by the Interface Builder, Interface Builder is from Apple, Three20 is just a separate open source project, not from Apple. See more from their site: [three20.info](http://three20.info)